# What is slinky-approximation?

Tags: waves

I was reading the derivation of wave-equation from Berkeley Physics - Waves by Frank S. Crawford Jr.

> Let $\Delta z$ be a small segment of a continuous string . At equilibrium, tension is $T_0$ at both ends. When it moves upwards, it no longer remains straight. $T_1 \quad \&  \quad T_2$ are tensions at both ends making $\theta_1 \quad \& \quad \theta _2$ with the line parallel to the horizontal. The horizontal components of the tensions at the ends are, then, $T_1\cos\theta_1 \quad \& \quad T_2\cos\theta_2$ genergally denoted as $T\cos\theta$. Now, in **slinky-approximation**, $T$ is larger than $T_0$ by a factor of $\dfrac{1}{\cos\theta}$. Therefore, $$T\cos\theta = T_0$$.

Now, what is **slinky-approximation**? How is it used in the derivation of wave-equation here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The slinky approximation is essentially the assumption that the extensions we are dealing with (including the equilibrium length) are much greater than the natural length of the spring. For example, this is true in a slinky, which stretches to much greater lengths when you pull it than its natural length.

Thus, while we would normally have, for a length $x$ of string,
$$
T = k(x-a_0)
$$

where $a_0$ is the natural length, under the slinky approximation we can neglect $a_0$. This means that we get a tension approximately proportional to the length, $T \approx kx$, and the ratio of tensions for two different cases is approximately equal to the ratio of lengths.

Here, the length of the segment inclined at an angle $\theta$ due to extension is $\dfrac{L_0}{\cos\theta}$, where $L_0$ is the equilibrium length of the segment. The slinky approximation here directly leads to the relation
$$T_0 = T \cos\theta
$$